# Cannot save values in sharedpreferences using ASyncTask

Tags: android, twitter, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I'm developing a twitter client, I can log in and get access token successfully and display it, I want to save the token in shared preferences and use them later (to not make the user login every time)
i use a AsyncTask to get token, on postExecute I put Shared preferences but it force closes.

this is my Async:

```
private class GetAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String verifier = strings[0];
                try {
                    accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(verifier);
                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), accessToken.getToken());

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"nooooooooooooooooooooooo");

                }

            return null;
        }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

             Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
             editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN , accessToken.getToken());
             editor.putString(ACCESS_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret() ); 
             editor.commit();

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hola", 54).show();
             super.onPostExecute(result);
         }
        }
```

logcat is here:

```
  05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at tk.pidevelopers.floata.MainActivity$GetAccessTokenTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:168)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at tk.pidevelopers.floata.MainActivity$GetAccessTokenTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
05-26 16:52:27.843: E/AndroidRuntime(7948):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please include stacktrace.

Comment: where did you referenced Your sharedPrefs?

Comment: should pass the mSharedPreferences  through a constructor to the asynctask

Comment: Share stackTrace Also check "mSharedPreferences" variable, is it initialized? May be this is null.

Comment: Ensure you are creating mSharedPreferences.

Comment: added logcat , every thing is defined and initalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `mSharedPreferences` is `null`. You can override `onPreExecute` method of `AsynkTask` and create `SharedPreferences` object `mSahredPreferences` or you can do the same in `onPostExecute`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
     mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(<Name>, <Mode>);
     Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
     editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN , accessToken.getToken());
     editor.putString(ACCESS_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret() ); 
     editor.commit();

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hola", 54).show();
         super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Please note that you need to call `getSharedPreferences` on `Context` if you are not doing stuffs in `Activity`.

Comment: what to write in (<name> , <mode>) it gives syntax error